# Lifetime of an object when it's only referenced but not owned

Tags: rust, reference, ownership

Let's say I have this piece of Rust code:

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
struct TestStruct<'a> {
    attr: &'a str
}

impl<'a> TestStruct<'a> {
     fn new() -> TestStruct<'a> {
        TestStruct {
            attr: "This is an test value"
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let val = &mut TestStruct::new();
}
```

If I understand correctly, the `val` contains a reference to instance of TestStruct. And if I understand correctly variable `val` is not an owner of this instance, but it borrows it mutably. If so, then who's the owner of the TestStruct instance and when the lifetime of this instance ends?

Comment: Kind of unrelated, but the lifetimes of your `new()` method are very confusing and unnecessary. Those are the proper annotations: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=39d3c2c05284f65623aa7079c05fd2eb It works because `'static` can be converted to any lifetime, but it's still nonsense from the generic point of view.

Comment: It's also worth noting that the lifetime annotations are completely unrelated to the question; the same question applies for e.g. `let val = &mut String::new();`.